# Matching pattern only if it exists

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $SourceStr='Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: Prelim 3  Optional: Some stuff here';
#my $SourceStr='Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: Prelim 3';

my $RegEx = qr/Name: (.+)  Time: (.+)  State: (.+)  Optional: (.+?)(  |$)/;

if ($SourceStr =~ m/$RegEx/) {
   print "1=[$1]\n";
   print "2=[$2]\n";
   print "3=[$3]\n";
   print "4=[$4]\n";
}
```

When run with the first $SourceStr, it works as expected.  However, for the second one that is commented out, is there a way to have $4 populated with the empty string?

First string results:

```
1=[Rob]
2=[11/2/2011 1:47:30 PM]
3=[3]
4=[Some stuff here]
```

Second string results: No match

Want:

```
1=[Rob]
2=[11/2/2011 1:47:30 PM]
3=[3]
4=[]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a more specific regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @SourceStrA=('Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3  Optional: Some stuff here',
                'Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3');

my $RegEx = qr!Name:\s*(\w+)\s*Time:\s*([\d/]*\s*[\d:]*)\s*State:\s*(\d+)\s*(?:Optional:\s*(.*))?!;

for my $SourceStr (@SourceStrA) {
  print "$SourceStr\n";
  if ($SourceStr =~ m/$RegEx/) {
    print "1=[$1]\n";
    print "2=[$2]\n";
    print "3=[$3]\n";
    print "4=[$4]\n" if defined $4; 
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3  Optional: Some stuff here
1=[Rob]
2=[11/2/2011 13:47:30]
3=[3]
4=[Some stuff here]
Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3
1=[Rob]
2=[11/2/2011 13:47:30]
3=[3]
```

Comment: Thanks.  The results are close to what I need, however, $4 is returning "Optional: Some stuff here" instead of just "Some stuff here".  I tried to capture just the value but it's not working (is capture within capture permitted?).

Comment: @FooManChooZE I tweaked the regex to produce the desired output. Yes, you can nest as many capture groups as you like. To get the number of the group, count the opening parens `(`. If you want to have a group without capture, use the `(?: ... )` construct. Groups starting with `(?` do not increment the capture buffer count.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use a hash or something.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

#my $SourceStr='Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3  Optional: Some stuff here';
my $SourceStr='Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3';

my %Values;

while ($SourceStr =~ m/(\w+): (.+?)(?:  |$)/g) {
    $Values{$1} = $2;
}

if ($Values{Name} && $Values{Time} && $Values{State}) {
    print "1=$Values{Name}\n";
    print "2=$Values{Time}\n";
    print "3=$Values{State}\n";

    if (defined $Values{Optional}) {
        print "4=$Values{Optional}\n";
    } else {
        print "4=\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is existing code that can't be readily changed so I have limited flexibility.  All I can do is supply the RegEx in string format and expect the parsed values into the $n vars.

Answer (score 1):

The request seems weird, but here is a solution :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $SourceStr='Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3  Optional: Some stuff here';
#my $SourceStr='Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3';

my $RegEx = qr/Name: (.+)  Time: (.+)  State: (.+?)(?:  Optional: )?(.*)(  |$)/;

if ($SourceStr =~ m/$RegEx/) {
   print "1=[$1]\n";
   print "2=[$2]\n";
   print "3=[$3]\n";
   print "4=[$4]\n";
}
```

The trick was of course to use the `(?: )` syntax to have an additional group without changing the place of $4. Also, using `(?:  Optional: (.*))?` was incorrect (albeit more logical and robust), because it will imply that $4 will be undefined (and you need it to be an empty string), and the `use strict` pragma is printing a disturbing `Use of uninitialized value...` message.

Anyway, these requirements look more like an exercice than a real-life problem, aren't they ?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick and kept the RE easy to read!  The requirements are very real-life indeed.  There is an application that is driven/customized by dynamic perl functions.  The input requirement for one such function was the RegEx string only (i.e. expecting the parsed values to be assigned in sequence).

Comment: Ok, then I'm happy that it's working (don't forget to validate the answer, though...) ;)

Comment: Running some tests with real data, I noted that the value of "State" can consist of multiple words (e.g. "Prelim 1").  I tried to tweak your solution for this but couldn't quite get it right.  Note also that the keywords such as "State:" always have two spaces before them.  Thanks.

Comment: Got it to work now: `my $RegEx = qr/Name: (.+)  Time: (.+)  State: (.+?)(?:$|  )(?:Optional: )?(.*)/;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option that produces your desired results:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $SourceStr = 'Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3  Optional: Some stuff here';

#my $SourceStr = 'Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3';

my $RegEx = qr/Name: (.+)  Time: (.+)  State: (.+?)(?:\s+Optional: (.+))?$/;

if ( $SourceStr =~ $RegEx ) {
    print "1=[$1]\n";
    print "2=[$2]\n";
    print "3=[$3]\n";
    print '4=[' . ( $4 // '' ) . "]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Named-backreferences), it can be easier to deal with optional matches via named captures rather than numbered.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @SourceStr = (
  'Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3  Optional: Some stuff here',
  'Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3',
);

my $RegEx = qr/Name: (?<name>.+?)  Time: (?<time>.+?)  State: (?<state>.+?)(?:  Optional: (?<optional>.+?))?(  |$)/;

foreach (@SourceStr) {
  print "Input '$_'\n";
  if ( /$RegEx/ ) {
     print "Name = '$+{name}'\n";
     print "Time = '$+{time}'\n";
     print "State = '$+{state}'\n";
     print "Optional = '$+{optional}'\n" if $+{optional};
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

In fact it makes it so easy, that its almost easier just to dump the `%+` hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @SourceStr = (
  'Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3  Optional: Some stuff here',
  'Foo - Name: Rob  Time: 11/2/2011 13:47:30  State: 3',
);

my $RegEx = qr/Name: (?<name>.+?)  Time: (?<time>.+?)  State: (?<state>.+?)(?:  Optional: (?<optional>.+?))?(  |$)/;

use Data::Dumper;
foreach (@SourceStr) {
  print "Input '$_'\n";
  print Dumper \%+ if /$RegEx/;
}
```